# HttpContent Bad request {"error":{"message":"Mandatory parameter missed","error_key":null}}

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I'm trying to do a simple POST using HttpClient but I've been facing some issues with  `HttpRequestMessage.Content`. and `\n`
In short, if I hard code one of the required parameters without the `escape character`, for instance:

```cs
string value = "lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum";
request.Content = new StringContent("{\"requiredParameter\":\""+ value +"\}");
```

Everything works just fine.

However, if I concatenate the string as follows:

```cs
string value = "\norem ipsum \n" +
                       "lorem ipsum \n" +
                       "lorem ipsum\n";
or even
//string value = "\nlorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum";
request.Content = new StringContent("{\"requiredParameter\":\""+ value +"\}");
```

It doesn't and I get a Bad request:

```sh
Status code: BadRequest
{"error":{"message":"Mandatory parameter missed","error_key":null}}
```

#### Already tried

**System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize**

```cs
 var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
 {
           WriteIndented = true,
  };
string json = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(value, options);
```

**StringBuilder** since it's more appropriate for extensive string manipulation.

```cs
string value1 = "\nlorem ipsum \n";
string value2 = "lorem ipsum \n";
string value3 = "lorem ipsum\n";

 stringBuilder.Append(value1);
 stringBuilder.Append(value2);
 stringBuilder.Append(value3);

request.Content = new StringContent("{\"requiredParameter\":\""+ stringBuilder.toString() +"\}");
```

and, **Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"**

```cs
request.Content = new StringContent("{\"requiredParameter\":\""+ value +"\", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

Didn't work.

A minimal repro:

```cs
static async Task<string> postAsync(Uri uri, string postContent)
{
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), "https://www.url.com/"))
        {
                   request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("authority", "www.url.com");
                   request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*");
                   request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("x-oauth2-required", "true");                   
                   
                   request.Content = new StringContent("{\"requiredParameter\":\""+ value +"\}");

                   return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
      }
}                    

static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Uri uri = new Uri("www.uri.com");
    var postContent = GenerateDynamicStringContent(List<string> params);
    await PostAsync(uri, postContent);
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: If you debug and inspect the content for both cases after building the `StringContent`, is there a difference? It would probably also help if you inspected the raw HTTP requests using Fiddler or something similar

Comment: The only noticeable difference between the working and non-working scenarios is that you have spaces (`lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum`) in the working version and no spaces (`lorem ipsumlorem ipsumlorem ipsum`) in the non-working versions

Comment: Note that provded example is not reproducible, thus it's not suitable for StackOverflow. The issue is obfuscated json syntax. You may change field names and values but keep quotes, commas and brackets at thier places. Please update the question. Btw, I've posted some possible solution below.

Comment: @aepot, I apologize for the lack of info. Also, I've omitted an important element in my question: the \n character which I realize is the origin of my issue. I've already updated the question and added a minimal repro as well.

Comment: Updated the answer. I'm surprized that you ignored the link in the answer. It completely answers your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you're missing that you aren't really need any `string` operations to build JSON. `JsonSerializer` will do it for you.

Consider the following example.

```csharp
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Net.Http;
```

```csharp
public class Program
{
    private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    public async Task Main()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        values.Add("lorem1", "ipsum1");
        values.Add("lorem2", "ipsum2");
        values.Add("lorem3", "ipsum3");
        JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            WriteIndented = true // these Options are not mandatory, just for pretty json formatting for debugging purpose
        };
        string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(values, options);
        Console.WriteLine(json);
        string result = await PostJsonAsync("https://myapi.url/api", json);
        // handle result here
    }

    private static async Task<string> PostJsonAsync(string url, string json)
    {
        using HttpContent content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        using HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, url);
        request.Content = content;
        using HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
}
```

Output

```
{
  "lorem1": "ipsum1",
  "lorem2": "ipsum2",
  "lorem3": "ipsum3"
}
```

[How to serialize and deserialize (marshal and unmarshal) JSON in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-how-to)

**Update**

I fugured out that sent data breaks json structure and cause server failure at deserealize process.

Create data class then. It called Data Model. The link above describes how to do it in details but I'll show the example. Don't be afraid of reading. I already answered your question completely but you didn't figure it out.

```csharp
public class MyPostDataClass
{
    [JsonPropertyName("requiredParameter")] // the attribute needed only if Property name differs from the json field name
    public string RequiredParameter { get; set; }
}
```

Then simply

```csharp
string postContent = GenerateDynamicStringContent(List<string> params);
MyPostDataClass postData = new MyPostDataClass();
postData.RequiredParameter = postContent;
string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(postData);
string result = await PostJsonAsync("https://myapi.url/api", json);
```

Use the post method from the answer, remove redundant `Headers` setup, use my `StringContent` constructor. Don't setup any headers, `StringContent` will setup it properly for you. Don't instantiate `new HttpClient` per request, it's a mistake, use the way shown above.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I took at least a day to build and properly test my POST model, but it was worthy. + my code is quite cleaner now! All the best.

Answer (score 0):

There is the difference that in 2nd and 3rd options, no space between each of `lorem ipsum`.

If you give empty spaces in `concatenate` string (end of each line) and similarly in `stringBuilder` then they would be same as the first one.

**With Concatenate**

```
string value = "lorem ipsum " +
                       "lorem ipsum " +
                       "lorem ipsum ";
```

**With StringBuilder**

```
string value1 = "lorem ipsum ";
string value2 = "lorem ipsum ";
string value3 = "lorem ipsum";

 stringBuilder.Append(value1);
 stringBuilder.Append(value2);
 stringBuilder.Append(value3);
```